# How to create 3D dataframe from 2D Raster in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, gis

I have a numpy code which is giving me the desired output:

```
testing = np.array([arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x,nodata_to_value=np.nan) for x in list_arr])
print testing.shape
(365, 25, 23)
```

Where my list_arr variable is containing all the names of the raster files:

```
print list_arr
['D:\\BiasCorrection\\Raw_Data\\PeejushData\\BangladeshStationBox025\\2014\\2014_001_025.img','D:\\BiasCorrection\\Raw_Data\\PeejushData\\BangladeshStationBox025\\2014\\2014_002_025.img..........
```

Is there any way to do this achieve the similar output in pandas DataFrame? instead of using numpy.array().

I want to output to be as following:

```
print pd.DataFrame([arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x,nodata_to_value=np.nan) for x in list_arr]).shape
(365, 25, 23)
```

But when I run the command above i get error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/BiasCorrection/Testing.py", line 35, in <module>
    print pd.DataFrame([arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x,nodata_to_value=np.nan) for x in list_arr]).shape
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.py", line 281, in __init__
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.py", line 416, in _init_ndarray
    values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.17.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5252, in _prep_ndarray
    raise ValueError('Must pass 2-d input')
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Comment: Please add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you try [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-3d-ndarray-with-optional-axis-labels)? `print pd.Panel([arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(x,nodata_to_value=np.nan) for x in list_arr])` ?

Comment: While you can do this with a `Panel`, `pandas` isn't particularly well-suited to n-dimensional data.  You might have a look at `xarray` instead for pandas-like labeled axes for N-D data: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/why-xarray.html  Alternatively, you can always use a 3D numpy array.